# MediaRecorder.stop() failed: -1007 after restarting it

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I record video of my Android phone screen and send the result file after every 5 seconds of recording, splitted into chunks 65K bytes long because I use UDP. Here's the code:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(sendFile);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (screenRecorder.isRunning()) screenRecorder.stopRecord();
        try {
            byte[] videoBytes = new byte[65000];
            if (sendFile.exists()) {
                int piecesNumber = (int)(sendFile.length() / 65000) + 1;
                byte[] byteNum = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(piecesNumber).array();
                sock.send(new DatagramPacket(byteNum, byteNum.length, ia, 11111));
                for (int i = 0; i < piecesNumber; i++) {
                    fis.read(videoBytes);
                    DatagramPacket videoPack = new DatagramPacket(videoBytes, 65000, ia, 11111);
                    sock.send(videoPack);
                }
                try {
                    PrintWriter flusher = new PrintWriter(sendFile); // flush file for new part of vid
                    flusher.write("");
                    flusher.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("RECORDED", "Sent " + videoBytes.length + " bytes");
            } else Log.e("FILE", "Not found");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!screenRecorder.isRunning()) screenRecorder.startRecord();
    }
```

The code of the screenRecorder.startRecord() and stopRecord() is:

```
public boolean startRecord() {
    if (mediaProjection == null || running) {
        return false;
    }

    initRecorder();
    if (virtualDisplay == null) createVirtualDisplay();
    mediaRecorder.start();
    running = true;
    return true;
}

public boolean stopRecord() {
    if (!running) {
        return false;
    }
    running = false;
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    //mediaRecorder.reset();
    //virtualDisplay.release();
    //mediaProjection.stop();

    return true;
}
```

The reset() uncommenting doesn't change anything, the virtualDisplay.release() and mediaProjection.stop() are commented because I initialize the instances of VirtualDisplay and MediaProjection before starting the record and don't want to uninitialize them.

The 1st iteration of timer goes well, and I get the 1st 5 seconds of the video on the receiving PC. But at the next stop() call the current acitvity closes, and that's what I see in the error log:

```
    2019-03-14 12:01:37.121 18374-18473/com.petrsu.se.s2s E/MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007
2019-03-14 12:01:37.125 18374-18473/com.petrsu.se.s2s E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
    Process: com.petrsu.se.s2s, PID: 18374
    java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.native_stop(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(MediaRecorder.java:1415)
        at com.petrsu.se.s2s.ScreenRecorder.stopRecord(ScreenRecorder.java:80)
        at com.petrsu.se.s2s.DataTransfer$sendTask.run(DataTransfer.java:221)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

What could be the reason of such behaviour? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What's virtualDisplay.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed that: I shouldn't have commented the

```
virtualDisplay.release;
```

I should have released it at every stop and create again in startRecord():

```
public boolean startRecord() {
    if (mediaProjection == null || running) {
        return false;
    }

    initRecorder();
    createVirtualDisplay(); // no additional check
    mediaRecorder.start();
    running = true;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am using flutter framework and I encounter the same issue can you help me?